# undefined sequence

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, subscripts, superscripts

I'm writing complicated equations by latex and I'm keeping have error messages: for the first two equations I've "undefined control sequence"
and the third one I've:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)
(inputenc)  not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

These are my equations

```
\begin{document}
$sigma \textsupsub{2}{j}(x)\equiv \sum_{j\prime=1}{M}{W \textsupsub{2}{ij\prime (X)a_{j\prime}(X)}, j,=1,...,M $ %(8b)
$$T= min_j\epsilon [1,M]\Bigg\{ \frac {\epsilon a_0(X)}{\mu_j(X)|},\frac {\epsilon a_0(X)}^2{(\xi\textsupsub{2}{j}(x)})$$
Prob $\{X_m=b\mid X_{m-1}=a, X_{m−2}=c,...,X_0=e\}=Prob\{X_m=b\mid X_(m-1)=a\}$
\end{document}
```

it suppose to produce :[image: following equations]

Comment: Welcome! Can you complete your code so we can reproduce the error? You've tagged this `amsmath`: are you loading that? Which option are you passing to `inputenc`? Note that `$$` ought not be used for display maths in LaTeX documents prepared in the last couple of decades or so. So unless your document pre-dates that, you should update the syntax. What is `textsupsub` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Fine-tuning is left as an exercise for the reader ... Here's the first two, which compiles into something vaguely like the relevant targets. See if you can do the third and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sigma^{2}_{j}(x)\equiv \sum_{j\prime=1}^{M} f_{ij\prime}^{2} (X)a_{j\prime}(X), j,=1,...,M
\]

\[
  T = \min_{j\epsilon [1,M]}
    \Bigg\{
    \frac {\epsilon a_0(X)}{\mu_j(X)},
    \frac {(\epsilon a_0(X))^2}{\sigma_{j}^{2}(x)}
    \Bigg\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: vaguely like the target]